# If condition with Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

In my asp.net application I have two pages like new students and edit students. On the new student page I am passing general details like first name, last name, mobile number, email and register number.

Here RegNo should be unique. I am using Entity Framework for database connection. I'm checking with the condition to avoid the same RegNo being entered, like:

```
DataObject.Entities dataEntities = new DataObject.Entities();

if (!dataEntities.Students.Any(s => s.RegNo == RegNo))
{
    // my code here.
}
```

The same way for edit option, when try to change the RegNo. If it is allotted to some other student, it should not go into the update code.

I know if I use the same condition here, it will fail, because the RegNo is there in the database for this student (the one am trying to update), so if the RegNo is allotted for this particular student and not for other students it should be accepted, otherwise should go to else part.

I don't know how to check this using Entity Framework. Can anyone help me,please?

I've a column `StudentId`, it's an autoincrement column

I tried like

```
if (!dataEntities.Students.Any(s => s.RegNo == RegNo && s.StudentId != StudentId))
{
}
```

still it's not working.....

Comment: RegNo is being allotted after student creation by database, it's an auto-identity column, correct?

Comment: no, its a manually added column

Comment: Is it a key? Why don't make it auto-identity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just declared an object for the student table and tried like,

```
DataObject.Student student = dataEntities.Students.First(s => s.StudentId == 
                                                                     StudentId);

 if (!dataEntities.Students.Any(s => s.RegNo == RegNo &&
                                             s.StudentId != student.StudentId))
 {

 }
 else
 {
    throw new exception("RegNo already exists!");
 }
```

and its working for me

Answer (score 3):

```
 if(!dataEntities.Students.Any(s=>s.RegNo == RegNo && s != studentBeingUpdated))
```

Replace `studentBeingUpdated` with a variable containing a reference to the student that you are currently updating.

Comment: its not working I tried as u suggested, check my updated question

Comment: for example am trying to update the details of StudentId=20, if the given RegNo is allotted to "20" it should accept. the same way If I try to update with the RegNo which is allotted to someother student, it should fail

Comment: @Shanish: Then there's something else wrong. For debugging, I'd loop through `dataEntities.Student` and output `RegNo`, `StudentId` as well as the result of the expression `s.RegNo == RegNo && s.StudentId != StudentId`.

Answer (score 1):

you can set in database level.. ie if you set auto increment then you dont need to edit/ reassign id to someone else and there is no need for separate management for this.

Please tell me if i understood mistakenly. :)

Comment: no its not an auto increment column, its a manually added one